# Is there any function to update your web site when another site post something new?

Tags: javascript

As example, i want to update my item list every time Amazon add a new product, is possible to do it without knowing their system or DB?

Comment: Your server would have to periodically crawl the amazon product list and check for updates. Which actually isn't that difficult to do. I'd recommend using Node.js!

Comment: Some sites offer webhooks that you could use in your backend. I doubt that Amazon offers that tho.

Comment: amazon was just a example but i will search for node.js thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no!!! This is the disadvantage of relying on a 3rd party site for the content of your site. However, using the API of the site, whose data you want to access, can give this functionality, but this will not work for all the sites.

Answer (score 1):

If the 3rd-party site does not provide an API to access their data, you'll need to "scrape" the site of that data. In theory this is easy, however, large companies like Amazon deliberately attempt to foil scraping attempts. See an open source project dedicated to this exact prupose: https://github.com/adamlwgriffiths/amazon_scraper The author says it best:

> Amazon have resorted to moving more and more content into iFrames which this scraper can't handle. I envisage a time where most data will be inaccessible without more complex logic.
>
> I've spent a long time trying to get these scrapers working and it's a never ending battle. I don't have the time to continually keep up the pace with Amazon. If you are interested in improving Amazon Scraper, please let me know (creating an issue is fine). Any help is appreciated.

If you want to build a custom tool to scrape public websites, I would check out Node.js. It is popular due to its ability to query the page DOM effectively. There are some good writeups out there to get started: https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js